# "this" is undefined in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, ondestroy

I'm trying to unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` method of the component, but instance of `this` is already `undefined`.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService} from 'somewhere';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(
    private someService: SomeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = new Subscription();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log(this);  // **log shows that 'this' is 'undefined'**

    if (this?.subscription) 
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
   
  onNextClick() {
    this.subscription = this.someService
      .getSomething()
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log('HTTP response', res);
        },
        error: (err: unknown) => {
          console.log('HTTP Error', err);
        },
        complete: () => console.log('HTTP request completed.'),
      });
  }
}
```

`getSomethig` method of the service returns an Observable, that I subscribe to. I want to close that subscription in OnDestroy event, but by then `this` object is already undefined and subscription does not exist anymore.

Lots of examples online show this way of unsubscribing, however the subscription is usually done in OnInint event. In my case, the event happens after a button click.

How should I unsubscribe in this case?

Comment: Can you provide a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Answer (score 0):

try this way with TakeUntil:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService} from 'somewhere';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  constructor(
    private someService: SomeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.destroy$.next(true);
   this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
   
  onNextClick() {
     this.someService
      .getSomething().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log('HTTP response', res);
        },
        error: (err: unknown) => {
          console.log('HTTP Error', err);
        },
        complete: () => console.log('HTTP request completed.'),
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: in the ngOnDestory() method, you should call the next() first and then the complete() and not unsubscribe(), like this :
`this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();`

Comment: I tried this solution and it has the same result. 'this' is still undefined, so `destroy$` is unavailable in this case as well.

Comment: @Tschareck can u tell me  Why are consoling this ??
because the code execute fine and if ur components will destroy u will unsubscribe from the observable